# How do you find out what Version of Twitter Bootstrap you have installed?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, command-line

I looked for this question before on stack, and for some reason the answer provided did not work. I am wondering if there is an update to this, to check either in the command-line or else where.

Comment: What tools are you using (Node? NPM?), and which platform are you on?

Comment: Not sure what you are referring too when you say platform, I am not using Node, just getting started with Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: By platform I meant Windows, Linux, Mac or something else.

Answer (score 2):

Look in the stylesheet bootstrap.css

you will see where it says something of this nature

```
/*!
* Bootstrap v3.1.0 (http://getbootstrap.com)
* Copyright 2011-2014 Twitter, Inc.
* Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
*/
```

Comment: I would like to know directly from the desktop, for example through the command-line.

Comment: --bootstrap-version VERSION

Comment: For some reason this did not work, not sure why.. :O/